# Sftp files from Remote server to local server

Tags: linux, shell, sftp, file-transfer

Sorry if it's too much simple question. But I am Java developer, no idea of shell scripting.
I googled, but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.

My requirement

1. Connect to remote server using Sftp [authentication based on pub/pri
   keys]. A variable to point to private key file
2. Transfer files with
   specific extension [.log] to local server folder. Variable to set
   remote server path and local folder
3. Rename the transferred file in
   remote server
4. Log all the transferred files in a .txt file

Can any one give me shell script for this?

This is so far I framed from suggestions.
Still some questions left on my side ;)

```
export PRIVKEY=${private_key_path}
export RMTHOST=user@remotehost
export RMTDIR=/logs/*.log
export LOCDIR=/downloaded/logs/
export LOG=sucess.txt

scp -i $PRIVKEY $RMTHOST:$RMTDIR $LOCDIR
for i in 'ls -1 $LOCDIR/*.log'
do
   echo $i >> $LOG
done

ssh $RMTHOST -c "for i in `ls -1 $RMTDIR; do mv /logs/$i /logs/$i.transferred; done"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this approach?

> 1. Connect to remote server using Sftp [authentication based on pub/pri keys]. A variable to point to private key file
> 2. Transfer files with specific extension [.log] to local server folder. Variable to set remote server path and local folder

```
scp your_user@server:/dir/of/file/*.log /your/local/dir
```

> 4. Log all the transferred files in a .txt file

```
for file in /your/local/dir/*.log
do
   echo "$file" >> $your_txt
done
```

> 3. Rename the transferred file in remote server

```
ssh your_user@server -c "for file in /dir/of/file/*.log; do mv /dir/of/file/"$file" /dir/of/file/new_name_based_on"$file"; done"
```

Comment: Could you please append/write it as complete script file. Except ls and chmod [basic commands], no idea of linux scripting

Comment: If any file transfer fails, how do the for condition knows it?

Comment: Regarding the script file, it would be a matter of joining the parts I indicated. Please try first and then come back with specific questions.

Comment: Regarding the file transfer failing, there are different ways: for example you can do `2>/logfile` which will return the errors happening.

Comment: Thanks. But how the authentication is maintained here. we didn't mention anywhere regarding public/private keys

Comment: Well I read `[authentication based on pub/pri keys]` so I guessed it is not necessary to write the password.

Comment: Hi. I have updated the script. still my question is how do we know whether the file is successfully transferred before renaming it

Comment: Hi, you can check the logfile (`grep $your_file $logfile`) and depending on the result, rename or not.

Comment: that's right. but is not it too much? From my logic point. can't we do all things in single loop. For each file, transfer, log it and rename it and move to next file. rather than connecting again and checking log file to rename ...

Comment: It depends. I think it is better copying all files on one connection. Then, you check it. Finally, rename. If you connect and disconnect every time it can be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Use scp(secure copy) command to transfer file. You may also want to add the -C switch, which compresses the file. That can speed things up a bit. i.e. copy file1 from server1 to server2,

**On server1:**

```
#!/bin/sh
scp -C /home/user/file1 root@server2.com:/home/user
```

**Edit:**

```
#!/bin/sh
scp -i {path/to/pub/pri/key/file} /home/user/file1 root@server2.com:/home/user
```

Comment: To be open, i don't have idea about shell scripting. In present project as Java developer I have this situation and seeking help :)

Comment: This `scp -C /home/user/file1 root@server2.com:/home/user` is the command you have to enter in the shell console in order to transfer, securily, files to a remote server. As `scp` is based in SSH you need to authenticate yourself.

Comment: Correct, authentication is needed.

Comment: but how do we make use of public key authentication as we didn't mention anything here. This script will be run by CRON job